# Error in Solace Setting up Hyper-V Application not running

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, solace

I downloaded the community version of Solace and am using Hyper-V to run Solace. I was following the '**Setting up Hyper-V VMR Machine Images**'. However when I get to step 4 and type solacectl cli, I get the following:

```html
SoIOS Application solace is not running.
```

I have tried various things and cannot figure out where I am going wrong.
I am able to start the service but then when I check the status it says that it is Exited.
Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could occur if you have not provided the Solace VMR with enough resources while configuring it. Please ensure that there are at least 2 virtual processors and at least 4 GiB of RAM.

If you believe that the VMR has been configured correctly, please provide the output of sudo tail -n 100 /var/lib/docker/volumes/jail/_data/logs/debug.log so that more information can be obtained.

Comment: Hi thank you so much! I had to change RAM to 4 GB and that fixed my issue.